# Print List of string Multithreaded

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list which should print the values over multithread based on thread count.

```
public class Launcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> tests = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
    final int thread_count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
        new Demo(tests.get(i));
}}
public class Demo implements Runnable {
Thread t;
String tests;

Demo(String tests) {
    t = new Thread(this);
    this.tests = tests;
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Started "+tests);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Stop");

}}
```

It actually prints

Started A

Started B

Stop

Stop

But i want it to print

Started A

Started B

Stop

Stop

Started C

Started D

Stop

Stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot start `C`and `D`because you set `final int thread_count = 2;` and your loop stops after reaching `i < thread_count`. So if you want to get all startet in a 2 step loop, than enhance it with another loop like:

```
for(int s = 0; s < 3; s+2){
   for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
        new Demo(tests.get(i+s));}
}
```